# How to write an and operation in a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, math

```
mysql_query("insert into mytable (flow,holderid,amount,operator,ip,product,taskid,comment)values('-1','$memberid','$sum+5','$memberid','$ip','Expertise','$taskid','Publish a problem or task') ")or die(mysql_error());
```

I get an error about

> '$sum+5'

MySQL doesn't treat it as an and operation, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Just a note: It is a bad idea to pass and concatenate variables in this way, you should consider to parametrize your query with explicit data type and acceptable value ranges.

Comment: Seconded. Normally, I would have mentioned something about prepared queries in PDO (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), but I guess I was careless when writing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want MySQL to perform the addition, drop the single quotes around the addition; they make MySQL interpret the expression as a string (just as PHP would). If you want PHP to perform the addition, do as fucla writes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using PHP with MySQL, concatenate the query like: `'".($sum+5)."'`

Also, you would want to put curly brackets `'{$variable}'` around your variables that remain within the double quotes, otherwise it will just read it as text you want inserted rather than a variable.